# Static members in object literal

Tags: javascript, static

I can create static members in the function below like this:

```
function Base() {
        Base.mask = 0;
}
```

But I would like to create these static members in a literal object:

```
const Base = {
        // ?
};
```

Is that possible, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it like this:

```
const Base = {};
Base.constructor.mask = 0;
```